# How to install mmlspark

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, lightgbm

I am trying to deploy a `mmlspark.lightgbm` model on my pyspark code. I tried `pip install mmlspark` on master's ssh and I got that it is satisfied, but when I run my project I got again:

> mmlspark not found.

My code consists a spark session like this:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp").master("yarn").config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",20).config("spark.jars.packages", "com.microsoft.ml.spark:mmlspark_2.11:1.0.0-rc1").config("spark.jars.repositories", "https://mmlspark.azureedge.net/maven").getOrCreate()
```

And I import mmlspark:

```
from mmlspark.lightgbm.LightGBMClassifier import LightGBMClassifier
```

This runs locally without problems

Answer (score 0):

Different Dataproc versions come with different default Python environments. You can follow this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/python-configuration) to configure your Python environment and install packages.